# Python Parsing with regex

Tags: python

I received some help on parsing out my text files into lines using blocks. I am looking to string together the CHARACTER = 4 with all of his LINES = 2. The parsing is troubling me how to end the loop when pulling the data... Code and link to text document below.

```
filename = 'Inception.txt'
data = open(filename).read()
script = re.sub('(        )+', '\n', data)

leading_space_re = re.compile('^ +')

block_types = {
    2: 'LINE:      ',
    7: 'DIRECTION: ',
    8: 'DIRECTION: ',
    4: 'CHARACTER: ',
    }



g = []

for line in script.split('\n'):
# number of leading spaces designates block type
match = leading_space_re.match(line)
count = 0 if match is None else len(match.group())
current_block = block_types.get(count, 'UNKNOWN:   ')
g.append(tuple([current_block, count, line]))    


df = pd.DataFrame(g)
new_df = df[df[1].isin([2,4])]
cols =['TYPE','ID','OT']
new_df.columns =cols


j = []



for id1, id2,id3 in 

zip(new_df.ix[23:].iterrows(),new_df.ix[24:].iterrows()):
if id1[1]['ID']==4:
    if id2[1]['ID']==2:
        j.append((tuple([id1[1]['OT'],id2[1]['OT']])))
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2p7ALidr

Comment: Reference : https://github.com/Adrien-Luxey/Da-Fonky-Movie-Script-Parser/blob/master/movie_script_parser.py